# Consuming WMTS from Planet for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, wmts, planet

I have registered a trial account with PlanetLab to evaluate the basemap product. I could login to my account and can use the Explore (web). However, could not connect to the WMTS to use my account with ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

Does Planet allow me to connect to WMTS with my trial account?

Comment: Are you able to connect to WMTS at all (you should be able at least to do a GetCapabilites in a web browser)?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use WMTS with your trial account, you need to also sign up for the 14 day WMTS trial. You can do this on the [Basemaps product page](https://www.planet.com/products/basemap/). You'll get an email with instructions on how to set up your WMTS client.